# How to install a theme to a fresh magento v1.8 store

Tags: magento-1.8, installation

I have purchased the theme a couple of years ago from rocket theme.

I've looked at their install instructions and it's missing some details and never got it installed.

I just installed a fresh v1.8 magento store to start over and have a current copy of the theme but i am just not getting enough detailed install instructions for me to feel comfortable trying it.

Here's the instructions i have from rocket theme:

> https://rockettheme.com/docs/magento/themes/infuse/INDEX.md#how-to-install-the-theme

what are the missing details.

Comment: Hi Dee j, welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. We are more interested to know what's you have tried and specifically where you need assistance. Please update your question with more specific details like the error you are getting. At least try to explain what you have tried so far. Otherwise, the question seems too broad to answer.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I am not sure exactly how to proceed once I unzip the theme zip file.  i've been looking around at different sites and have found one place that says to unzip the file and upload everything to the magento root directory but I'm still not sure how to set up the theme in the admin side once I do that.